# How to set the value from the rest api call to ngModel on select tag after getting response in angular

Tags: angular

In my case there is dropdown I want to by default set the string value which I am getting from the response of API, I am trying to set the value using ngModel on select tag I tried using ChangeDectector doesn't works.

**component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label><small>Allocated Berth</small></label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="displayValue" (change)="onSelectBerth($event.target.value)">
        <option>Select Option</option>
        <option *ngFor=" let item of berthList" [value]="item.id"> {{(item.name)}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private berthService: BerthService,private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.berthService.getBerths().subscribe((response) => {
        this.berthList = response;
        for (let index = 0; index < this.berthList.length; index++) {
            if (this.berthList[index].id === this.allocatedBerthId) {
                this.displayValue = this.berthList[index].name;
                console.log('Display', this.displayValue);
                this.ref.detectChanges();
            }
        }
    },(error) => {
    });
}
```

I am getting displayValue on console.log but not on view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as value of the option is ID `<option [value]="item.id">` the model passed to ngModel should be also ID.
so

```
this.displayValue = this.berthList[index].id
```

should fix the issue